# Query to extract row without specific value

Tags: mysql, database

I have this table in my database:

```
 id   name             source
------------------------------
  1    John Doe          fbs
  2    Clara Wayne       fbs
  3    John Doe          dem
  4    Markus Clark      lp
  5    Markus Clark      fbs
  6    John Doe          sms
```

I need to extract something like this, where column `source` is neither `dem` nor `sms`:

```
 id   name             source
------------------------------
  2    Clara Wayne       fbs
  4    Markus Clark      lp
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume, `John Doe` is not selected as one of the record of him belongs to `sms` source which you don't want to include in the results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE name NOT IN (
  SELECT name
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  WHERE source IN ('dem','sms')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN SELECT THE DATA LIKE....

```
    SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE SOURCE NOT IN ('DEM', 'SMS')
```

OR YOU CAN DO SOETHING LIKE THIS...

```
   SELECT DISTINCT SOURCE, NAME, ID FROM TABLE_NAME T WHERE T.NAME NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE SOURCE IN('DEM', 'SMS'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table where source != 'dem' and source != 'sms'
```

another way to go about it

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list of "not desired values" like this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE source NOT IN ('fbs','lp');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

`SELECT Distanct name,source FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE SOURCE NOT IN ('DEM', 'SMS')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE id = t.id 
        AND name = t.name 
        AND source IN ('dem', 'sms')
)
```